# Magento 2.4 installation through command line

Tags: magento2.4

[image][image]

I have tried installing magento 2.4 through command line. But it is showing error like encryption key not specified. Can anyone please help? I am using windows 10

Comment: I think secure url will not work on localhost,try --base-url="http://localhost/magento/" instead of "--base-url-secure="https://localhost/magento/"

Comment: @Pawan the problem is when i hit localhost/magento , it is showing just setup landing page without continue button

Comment: @Pawan see the first screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento" \
--db-host="127.0.0.1:3308" \
--db-name="magento" \
--db-user="root" \
--db-password="" \
--admin-firstname="admin"  \
--admin-lastname="admin"  \
--admin-email="admin@admin.com"  \
--admin-user="admin"  \
--admin-password="admin123"  \
--language="en_US"  \
--currency="USD"  \
--timezone="America/Chicago"  \
--use-rewrites="1"  \
--backend-frontname="admin"  \
--elasticsearch-host="127.0.0.1:9200"
```

Comment: i think elastic search wont work in local. Can i disable that modules?

Comment: elasticseach is mandatory in magneto 2.4 according to Docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html#elasticsearch

Comment: Will it work in local?

Comment: yes it works on local if you want installation guide i can provide you

Comment: yes please provide. I am using wamp

Comment: are you using windows or ubuntu?

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: magento can;t be installed on windows see docs again `Linux distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, and similar. Magento is not supported on Microsoft Windows and macOS.

`

Comment: Don't even try to run Magento2 on Windows, with or without Elasticsearch. It will be terribly slow and you will waste your time. Just start using Linux or Mac.